# How to interpret the expected value of the pdf of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Suppose we have a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathcal{X}$, with pdf $f_X$. It is clear that the expectation of any function of $X$, say $g(X)$, is

$$E[g(X)] = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}}g(x)f_X(x)dx$$

Suppose we wish to take the expectation of the random variable $f_X(X)$, (in other words, what value the pdf will take in expectation), such that

$$E[f_X(X)] = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}}f_X(x)f_X(x)dx = \int_{x \in \mathcal{X}}f^2_X(x)dx$$

Does this expectation have any meaningful interpretation?

Comment: I do not know this particular interpretation right off the bat, but a related concept is [Entropy in information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29).

Comment: In some sense, you can see $E[f_X(X)]$ as giving the "Expected value" of the pushforward probability measure $\mu_X$ of $X$ with respect to its own measure. This is related to the second moment of $X$, and you can see this by computing $E[f_X(X)]$ for $X = N(\mu, \sigma)$. In this case, $E[f_X(X)] = \frac{1}{2\sigma\sqrt{\pi}}$.